# Filter list with complex expression

Tags: python, lambda

```
arr = [[2,6,8],[1,4,7],[3,3,4],[2,4,9],[3,3,7]]

array_analysis = lambda arr=[], evenOdd=True, no_doubles= True:list(i for i in arr if evenOdd == True len(set(i) % 2) if no_doubles == True len(set(i) !> 1)

# test it
print('test array', arr)
for evenOdd, no_doubles in ((True, True), (True, False), (False, True), (False, False)):
    print(evenOdd, no_doubles, array_analysis(arr, evenOdd, no_doubles))
```

I am attempting to create a lambda function that will filter an array list based on conditional arguments.

- If all lambda arguments are `True`, the return value should be: `[[1,4,7],[2,4,9]]` because there are no all odd or all evens no doubles in number set.
- If `no_doubles` is `False`, it a should include the doubles that have no all even or no all odds. Return value should be `[[1,4,7],[2,4,9],[3,3,4]]` doesn't include set `[3,3,7]` because it's all odd.
- If `oddEven` is `False` and `no_double` is false the return value should be all numbers vice versa. If `oddEven` is `False` and `no_double` is `True`, the return value should be `[[3,3,4],[3,3,7]]`

Without lambda

```
# filters all odd or all even
def oddEven(a):
    return [i for i in a if len(set(np.mod(i, 2)))!=2]

# filters doubles
def no_doubles(a):
    return [i for i in a if len(set(i))!>2]

def all_filters_combined(a):
    return oddEven(a) and no_doubles(a)
```

This is almost what I'm looking for but its not using lambda and it doesn't allow me to choose if I want to change the filtering. How can I change this code to allow me to choose the filter in one lambda function?

Comment: Please format your code correctly, this is unreadable and ambiguous.

Comment: For starters, why do you insist it to be a `lambda`?

Comment: I'm lost ... could you show the desired output for all four combinations of evenOdd and no_doubles True and False?

Comment: Python has this neat thing called functions that allow conditions...

Comment: I think I covered every possible outcome.

Comment: I am looking for a way to filter tuples based on conditions. I want to return number sets that have a mixture of odds and even digit if oddEven is True, and no double digits if no_double is True.

Comment: I've done it without the lambda function.

Comment: if `oddEven` is false, do you accept everything or just lists that have mixed odd and even values? If `no_double` is false, do you accept all lists or only those with doubles?

Comment: I think people are commenting because when you do `array_analysis = lambda...` you've mostly lost the advantage of lambdas and might as well just stick with your function. The exercise here, I think, is to convert an `if...else` thing into a single expression. You are missing the logical `and` and `or`s to put it all together.

Comment: I have the answer but this question but can't post it because the question is closed. The question I think is how you can filter the list with a single expression instead of a function with `if...else` clauses. Maybe you can edit and repost.

Comment: This is a question about writing complex expressions which I think is on-topic and should be reopened.

Comment: @user5474113 - reopening takes forever! this will work for you: `array_analysis = lambda arr=[], evenOdd=True, no_doubles= True: list(i for i in arr if (not evenOdd or sum(x & 1 for x  in i) in (0, len(i))) and (not no_doubles or (len(set(i)) == len(i))))`

Comment: @tdelaney oddEven if oddEven is False elements with all odds or all evens won't be filter and yes all number will return then the numbers will enter the no_doubles filter. If no_doubles is False all numbers will remain, if no_doubles is True no doubles will show up. This is a bit complex

Comment: Hope that's close! May need a little tweeking.

Comment: If you have done it without using a lambda, then show your code doing it without a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want...

```
arr = [[2,6,8],[1,4,7],[3,3,4],[2,4,9],[3,3,7]]

foo = lambda arr, evenOdd, noDoubles: [ i for i in arr if not (evenOdd and (all(k % 2 == 1 for k in i) or all(k%2 == 0 for k in i))) and not (noDoubles and (len(i) != len(set(i))))]

print(foo(arr, False, False))
print(foo(arr, True, False))
print(foo(arr, False, True))
print(foo(arr, True, True))

 $ python3 foo.py
[[2, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7], [3, 3, 4], [2, 4, 9], [3, 3, 7]]
[[1, 4, 7], [3, 3, 4], [2, 4, 9]]
[[2, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7], [2, 4, 9]]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 4, 9]]
 $
```

Let's break it down a little.

`[ i for i in arr if ... ]` - You can use list comprehensions to do filtering like this.  We just need to make sure that `...` evaluates to `True` or `False` correctly depending on the element.

`not (evenOdd and (all(k % 2 == 1 for k in i) or all(k%2 == 0 for k in i)))` - This is the evenOdd test.  If `evenOdd` is `False`, then the statement will short circuit to `True`, meaning the element should not be filtered.  If `evenOdd` is `True`, then `all(k % 2 == 1 for k in i)` tests if each element of `i` is odd (and the next test checks for even).

`and` - If either test fails, the element should be filtered.

`not (noDoubles and (len(i) != len(set(i))))` - If `noDoubles` is `False`, then the expression short circuits to `True`.  If `noDoubles` is `True`, then `len(i) != len(set(i)))` is just a dirty test for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much, the True True doesn't return anything. I am currently tweaking it to make it work. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: `True, True` *should* return `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 4, 9]]`.  My code example included a run of the program with that result.

Comment: Please remember to accept my question with a check if it fixed your issue.

Comment: Sorry for that, checked it in Python 3.4.3, and it works perfectly. Amazing! Didn't in Python 2.7, you're a life saver